# It always gives undefined reference error

Tags: c++

I am writingthat code but gives me undefined reference error. Here is the error : undefined ref. yo display students , undefined reference to adCourse

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include "Course.h"
  #include "Student.h"
  #include "StudentReviewSystem.h"

 using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
    // create GradeBook object
    Course s( 201, "CS");
    cout << "name : " << s.courseName << endl;
    cout << "ID : " << s.courseID << endl;
    cout << "Enter student ID :" << endl;
    int ID;
    cin >> ID;
    cout << "Enter student name :" << endl;
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    s.addStudent(ID,name);
   //    cout << "You add the student with name: " << s.studentName << "  and ID : " << 
    cout << "Enter student ID :" << endl;
    int ID2;
   cin >> ID2;
   cout << "Enter student name :" << endl;
  string name2;
  cin >> name2;
    s.addStudent(ID2,name2);
    s.displayStudents();

   StudentReviewSystem ilknur;
    ilknur.addCourse(111,"HUM");
   cout << ilknur.courses[0].courseID;


 return 0; // indicate successful termination
 }
```

Comment: Looks like you're not linking in the object files produced by the .cpp files which contain the definition of the stuff you `#include`. Also, reporting at least one exact, unedited, full linker error message is usually a good thing (rather than summing it up in words).

Comment: Sorry I did not understand ?

Comment: Well, `Course.h` probably contains a `Course` class with a few member functions. These member functions are (I assume) defined in some `.cpp` file. If they aren't, that's of course the problem. If they are, then the result of the compilation of that .cpp file is not being given in input to the linker, so the linker looks for the definition of `addStudent()` but cannot find any (similarly for other functions).

Comment: yes how can I fix this ?

Comment: It seems to me you are not aware of how compilation/linking works in C++. I suggest you reading about it and being aware of what is going on if you intend/have to write C++ code. [Here](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/11/compiling-and-linking) is some basic information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linker is telling you that your files has an external dependency it cannot resolve.

Probably you need to include the path to the soruce code (StudentReviewSystem.c) to your project paths. That's how you would solve it in Eclipe. VS adds everything it need when you add files to the project.

Comment: maybe it's worth mentioning what environment you are using to build this code.

Answer (score 0):

Every cpp file has to be compiled and linked in order to get an executeable. (If no external libraries are used this should do at least.)

If that hint does not help, please post your compiler and linker commands or the whole bild output.

Comment: What do you mean by linked ?